# PyGraphViz agraph.layout() throws I0 error

Tags: python, pygraphviz

After running the following Python code:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
G=pgv.AGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.layout(prog='dot')
G.draw('1.png')
```

I got this trace in IDLE:

```
 File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
   G.layout(prog='dot')
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1302, in layout
   data=self._run_prog(prog,' '.join([args,"-T",fmt]))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1275, in _run_prog
   raise IOError("".join(errors))
 IOError: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Please help, I am working on a course project.
Information:
Graphviz installed correctedly

Comment: Could you post some more detail? We'll need, for example, the section code that generated this traceback, and of course what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for viewing my post. Please have a look i just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug with your version of PyGraphViz and Windows. I found [this bug ticket](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/582) describing it, but it was apparently fixed in 2011. It looks like they haven't actually released the update, but it should be in their SVN if you can switch to that.

If not, and you don't mind editing the source yourself, the actual fix they made is [really trivial](https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/changeset/1986/networkx-svn-archive). Just find `agraph.py`, and change this line:

```
runprog=self._get_prog(prog)
```

to

```
runprog=r'"%s"'%self._get_prog(prog)
```

Comment: @AdnanAlamKhan I take it one of those options worked? Which one? I'll note it in the answer. (By the way, if it *did* work, you can mark this question as accepted -- helps us both out and lets others with this question know that the answer worked for you.)