# Format: "png" not recognized at pygraphviz Python, Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, graphviz, buildpack

The following code:

```
import pygraphviz as p

def main():
    A=p.AGraph()
    A.add_edge(1,2)
    A.layout(prog="dot")
    A.draw("1.png")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

wokrs fine locally, but when launched via Heroku bash it returns IO Error:

```
Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of: canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz xdot
```

I used this buildpack to upload graphviz

```
heroku config:get BUILDPACK_URL
    https://github.com/mfenniak/heroku-buildpack-python-graphviz.git
```

Here is my `requierments.txt` file:

```
Django==1.7.1
argparse==1.2.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.1.1
psycopg2==2.5.4
pygraphviz==1.3rc2
static3==0.5.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Local `graphviz` version:

```
dpkg -p graphviz
    Version: 2.26.3-10ubuntu1.1
```

As for Heroku `graphviz` version, I am not sure but I found this line in buildpack's `bin/compile` file:

```
GRAPHVIZ_BINARY="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mfenniak-graphviz/graphviz-2.30.tgz"
```

`pygraphviz` has the same version on Heroku and locally

**UPD:** How to at least check Heroku's graphviz version?

**UPD** `dot` version at heroku does not have `png` in device section. How to fix that?

```
dot -v
dot - graphviz version 2.30.1 (20130508.0026)
libdir = "/app/mfenniak/graphviz/lib/graphviz"
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.so.6
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_core.so.6
Using render: dot:core
Using device: dot:dot:core
The plugin configuration file:
    /app/mfenniak/graphviz/lib/graphviz/config6
        was successfully loaded.
    render  :  dot fig map pic pov ps svg tk vml xdot
    layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  : 
    device  :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap pic plain plain-ext pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz xdot
    loadimage   :  (lib) eps gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
```

This thread looks similar but unfortunately is not my case.
[PyGraphViz agraph.layout() throws I0 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513085/pygraphviz-agraph-layout-throws-i0-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there isn't png support in your graphviz executable.  Run 'dot -v' to see the supported formats.  It looks like e.g. 'svg' is so you could try `A.draw("1.svg")`.

Comment: Looks like I realy do not gave png in device section. Any ideas how to fix that? Updated.

Comment: Yep, but no `png` listed in device:

Comment: Could you suggest how to add it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427184/dot-doesnt-support-any-format-in-a-newly-installed-graphviz Here is kind of answer, but how to do that at Heroku?

Comment: I guess you need to install (maybe compile) a version of graphviz with the png support built in.  Either that or maybe you can use a different format or convert to png from another format?

Comment: graphviz-2.30 should support png, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, graphviz-2.30 does support png but it is optional like many of the device outputs.  So you need a version with it configured and compiled in to the binary.

Comment: could you suggest a direct link to the file in `.tgz` format so that i could replace it in my buildpack code?
GRAPHVIZ_BINARY="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mfenniak-graphviz/graphviz-2.30.tgz

Answer (score 1):

I have also met this problem。It bothered me a lot.
However, when I happened to type the code below:

```
import pydot
print pydot.find_graphviz()
```

It shows that the path lead to matlab but not Graphviz
Then I understand this maybe the reason
So I uninstall the matlab and finally solve this problem!

I wonder if your PC also installed matlab, then try this way. May it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried re-install graphviz again as suggested in the last ticket, the error is still there. Probably I am not configuring it correctly.

Anyway, if you are using Debian/Ubuntu system.

Try:

`sudo apt-get install graphviz`

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygraphviz
```

Comment: I can do these commands locally, but I can not do them on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, and I hope this can help someone who still using the package especially in Windows, just do

```
dot -c
```

this will basically configure dot for you